# Is there a difference in effect between Black soul gems and others?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Black Soul Gem for?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36719/what-is-the-black-soul-gem-for)

I know that black soul gems can only hold humanoid souls, while the others generally handle animal, undead, and other types of souls.  Souls in black gems are also always of the Grand variety.

Is there any difference in potency or otherwise, between black Grand souls and regular Grand souls?

Comment: this is a DUP of previous questions,i just don't have the links or know how to designate it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they work exactly the same, only differing in the Soul Trapping stage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Black Soul gems to make deadra hearts for Dedric Armor & wepons.